# Multi-stop linear gradient for IE 7-10

Tags: internet-explorer, css, linear-gradients

So I'm familiar with just a simple gradient using filters and PIE, but how would I do a multiple stop/start gradient with the same tools?:

```
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom , #0C355C 0%, #082540 50%, #0C355C 51%, #0F4476 100%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #0C355C), color-stop(0.5, #082540), color-stop(0.51, #0C355C), color-stop(1, #0F4476));
```

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ (The easy way)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using this:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

EXAMPLE:

```
background: #1e5799; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 50%, #207cca 51%, #7db9e8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1e5799), color-stop(50%,#2989d8), color-stop(51%,#207cca), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Comment: The IE gradient filter only allows for 2 color stops (first and last), which doesn't help the OP much if 3 or more are needed.

Comment: Yeah - That's the one problem. Can this be accomplished with Pie? Or do I have the go the route of an image..?

Comment: @user82302124: PIE wont help here, traditional Image is the best option

Comment: That's what I ended up doing - just an image.

Comment: The multistop gradients are an option on colorzilla. Do check the 'ie9 support' checkbox. it provides you with a svg fallback that looks like `background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lv......` and requires some extra conditional comments.

Comment: .. but thats only ie9. ie6-8 still only have 2 stops.